# Overriding a class' "is" attribute (Moose)

Tags: perl, moose

I am trying to subclass an `ro` attribute to make it `rw` like so:

```
has '+content' => (is => 'rw');
```

This doesn't seem to work though. Is this not possible?

Comment: Maybe `has '+content' => (accessor=>'content');`? But rather than changing the behaviour of `$o->content`, why not add a `writer` instead?

Comment: I tried adding a writer. Maybe I don't know how it works, though. Because I got the same `Cannot assign a value to a read-only accessor` error.

Comment: If it works, it would be `has '+content' => (writer=>'set_content');` then `$o->set_content($new_value)`

Comment: Ah, got it now. Thanks.

Comment: Neither are particularly nice solution. The base class you should be updated to support what you need it to support.

Answer (score 1):

You should define an object as read-only and then provide a private writer

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

{
    package Foo;
    use Moose;

    has bar => (
      is     => 'ro',
      writer => '_set_bar',
  );

}

my $foo = Foo->new;
```

Then if you try to `$foo->bar('something');` you will get the error you mentioned in the comment `Cannot assign a value to a read-only accessor` and here is the magic you need `$foo->_set_bar('something');` 
Thanks to inheritance it will work thorough Moose framework.